# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]' in IOS

Tags: ios, exception, nsarray, uncaught-exception, nsrangeexception

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    data_web *current_data ;
    current_data = [[structured_question data_webs] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *is_submited = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[current_data content_2]];

    if ([is_submited compare:@"Y"] == NSOrderedSame)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


}
```

Above is my script. something is wrong in my script and I cannot find a solution.

Comment: What solution are you looking for? The `row` is 5, valid indexes are 0..4, you need to make sure that `data_webs` has enough rows.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return [[testM data_webs] count];
    else
        return [[testS data_webs] count];
}

is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comment you provided the code for your `numberOfRowsInSection` method as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0)
        return [[testM data_webs] count];
    else
        return [[testS data_webs] count];
}
```

However, your `willDisplayCell` ignores `indexPath.section` when you access `current_data`. When the cell from a section that has more rows is displayed, your code will crash.

You should change your code to something like this:

```
NSArray *data_webs;
// This part mimics your "numberOfRowsInSection'
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    data_webs = [testM data_webs];
} else {
    data_webs = [testS data_webs];
}
data_web *current_data ;
current_data = [data_webs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I do not know what's `structured_question` in your code was, and why you were using it, but the above should eliminate the crash in the `objectAtIndex:` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help @dasblinkenlight. It solve the issue.